# Unity3D MonoDevelop editor can't point to right Unity API reference

Tags: unity-game-engine

With this code:

```
Transform transf;
transf.lossyScale;
```

when I attempt manual `lossyScale` with Ctrl+' direct to https://unity3d.com/cn/support/documentation/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=lossyScale
It's 404.Actually, right url is https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-lossyScale.html or local url: file:///Applications/Unity/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-lossyScale.html

The Unity version is latest at this time: 5.4.1f1

**Others attempt**

[redirector plugin on bowser](http://einaregilsson.com/writing-a-browser-extension-for-three-browsers/)
,show as above, I can't simple find the error url how to match right one.

[a shell](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/30436/launching-local-unity-api-reference-from-monodevel.html)
It's not work for my Mac.

How can I get right API manual url?

Comment: It probably means that the doc generated with unity's libraries aren't up to date (because its a recent version). Does this happen with other unitys classes ? If so, you should report this as a bug.

Comment: it works for me, on my Macbook with Unity 5.4.1p1. Command-' clicking leads to https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=lossyScale which is not a 404 page. You do need to  click on the link there to the actual page for lossyScale though.

Comment: @Asoub, yes. I will consider report this problem.

Comment: @frankhermes, Maybe I'm at China area,which url contains *cn*, make the url different with yours.

Comment: ^ this helped me. Just change the unity page to another language and then back to englisch

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue. Described in Unity's Fogbugz (https://fogbugz.unity3d.com/f/cases/732246/).

As a workaround, you might switch to English local and search for Unity API from MD again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!!

In my case when I oppened unity3d.com on my browser it was in spanish, so I went to the bottom of unity3d.com and selected spanish and then I switch back to english, and it worked!, I hope this would be helpfull to someone.